# useEffectの挙動について

Tags: reactjs, typescript

useEffectの挙動について質問させていただきます。
console.logで出力する値が遅れて出力されるのはなぜか というのが主旨になります。

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

type inputSetting = {
    player : number;
    wolves : number;
    civil : number;
    timer : number;
}

export default function GameSetting() {

    const initialSetting = {
        player: 3,
        wolves: 1,
        civil: 2,
        timer: 2
    }

    const [property, setProperty] = useState<inputSetting>(initialSetting);

    const decrementPlayer = () => {
         setProperty({ ...property, player: property.player - 1 });
    }
    const incrementPlayer = () => {
         setProperty({ ...property, player: property.player + 1 });
    }

    // U1
    useEffect(() => {
        setProperty({...property, civil: property.player - property.wolves});
    },[property.player]);
    
    // U2
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(property.civil);
    },[property.player]);

    return(
        <div className="flex gap-2">
            <button onClick={() => incrementPlayer()} className="border">+</button>
            <button onClick={() => decrementPlayer()} className="border">-</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

上記のコードでは、`player`の増減を行うとU1・U2が発火し`civil`の計算、計算後の`civil`の値を出力するという仕掛けになっています。

1回目に `+` ボタンをクリックした場合`console.log`で 「**3**」 が出力される想定ですが、なぜか計算前の「**2**」が表示されます。

2回目に `+` ボタンをクリックすると「**3**」が表示されます。

順序としては

1. `+` ボタンクリック
2. `civil`の計算
3. `console.log`で`civil`出力

という認識ですが、何故値が遅れて出力されるのでしょうか。ご教示ください。

#### 環境

- React 18.2.0
- TypeScript 4.8.4
- macOS Monterey 12.6
- Chrome 106.0.5249.103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[useEffec フック API リファレンス – React](https://ja.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) の「補足」にはこう書かれています

> この最適化を利用する場合、 **時間の経過とともに変化し副作用によって利用される、コンポーネントスコープの値（props や state など）** がすべて配列に含まれていることを確認してください。さもないとあなたのコードは以前のレンダー時の古い値を参照してしまうことになります。...

まさしく、この補足で指摘した状況になってしまっていると思われます。

`property.player`が変更されたとき、U1とU2が実行されるのですが、これらU1とU2が実行されるときの`property`は`useEffect()`によって実行が予約されたときの値です。どういうことかというと、U1で`setProperty`で`property`の値を変えても、その値は次のサイクルの`property`であって、既に実行が予約されているU2での`property`とは別のオブジェクトになると言うことです。別の言い方で言うと、U1が実行されるときの`property`と同じ`property`をU2が実行されるときも見に行っています。それは、`civil`を変更する前のものなので、相変わらず`2`になると言うことです。

もし、`civil`が変更されて、その結果を見たければ、次のように書くべきでしょう。

```
// U2
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(property.civil);
},[property.civil]);
```